# How to programatically set height of view with appbar_scrolling_view_behavior?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I Have the below layout.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppBarLayout>
<CollapsingToolbarLayout>
<Toolbar>
</CollapsingToolbarLayout>
<View1>
<View2>
</AppBarLayout>
<RecyclerView>(appbar_scrolling_view_behavior)
```

On one use case, I use an empty state viewholder to show that there are empty items from api.Also I have to hardcode the height of the recyclerview relative to the screenheight. As a result, on scrolling of the recyclerview fully up there is some space left below the empty state of the recyclerview.I do not want this space.Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerview.scrollToPosition(0)
val params = appbar.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
val behavior = params.behavior as AppBarLayout.Behavior?
if (behavior != null) {
  val valueAnimator: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt()
  valueAnimator.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
  valueAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
    behavior.topAndBottomOffset = (animation.animatedValue as Int)
    appbar.requestLayout()
  }
  valueAnimator.setIntValues(
    0, -appbar.totalScrollRange + view2.measuredHeight
  )
  valueAnimator.duration = 50
  valueAnimator.start()
}
```

Found this approach to work after trying other approaches.